# tkinter: why does this movable label move when i don't move it?

Tags: python-3.x

i have a moveable label. its position is read from a txt file and wrote to txt file when it was changed by dragging. 
but the position of the label changes when i don't drag it, just by running the snippet.

i tried it with multiple labels and found out that each time i run the snippet the x and y of every single moveable label increment with the same number.

```
import tkinter as tk

def make_draggable(widget):
    widget.bind("<Button-1>", on_drag_start)
    widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag_motion)

def on_drag_start(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget._drag_start_x = event.x
    widget._drag_start_y = event.y

def on_drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget._drag_start_x + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget._drag_start_y + event.y
    widget.place(x=x, y=y)

def get_new_positions():
    x, y = label1.winfo_rootx(), label1.winfo_rooty()
    positions["moveable_label"] = (x, y)


    dictfile = open("labelposition.txt", "w")   # save new positions
    dictfile.write(str(positions))
    dictfile.close()

def close_window():
    main.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1200x900')

tk.Label(root, text="test").pack()


root.withdraw()

# start window
aWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
aWindow.geometry('1200x900')

def change_window():
    # call function which reads the y coordinates
    aWindow.update()
    get_new_positions()
    #remove the other window entirely
    aWindow.destroy()

    #make root visible again
    root.iconify()
    root.deiconify()

tk.Button(aWindow, text="OK", command=change_window).pack()

# load dict with label positions

dictfile = open("labelposition.txt", "r")
positions = eval(dictfile.read())  # load label positions
dictfile.close()

# position label

label1 = tk.Label(aWindow, text="moveable")
label1.place(x=positions["moveable_label"][0], y=positions["moveable_label"][1])
make_draggable(label1)

root.mainloop()
```

The goal of my code snippet should be:

1. show a moveable label and position it according to the x y data saved in a txt file.
2. if the label is moved to another position with the mouse and the ok button is klicked, the new x y position is saved to the txt file.
3. a new empty page opens

but: when i run the snippet multiple times without touching the label with the mouse, the label position changes its position every time anyway (x and y get higher)

can you see where this x y change comes from?

Comment: Can you include the contents of labelposition.txt?

Comment: {'moveable_label': (0, 0)}

Answer (score 0):

The reason the location keeps changing throughout runs is because the method you use to capture the x and y coordinates of your widget return the coordinates relative to the top left corner of the *screen*, not the parent.

> winfo_rootx():
>
> Get the pixel coordinate for the widget’s left edge, relative to the screen’s upper left corner.
>      Returns: The root coordinate.

Instead of using `winfo_root*`, use `winfo_*`, which returns the location relative to the parent window.

> winfo_x():
>
> Returns the pixel coordinates for the widgets’s left corner, relative to its parent’s left corner.

So inside your `get_new_positions` function, the x and y coordinates should be:

```py
def get_new_positions():
    x, y = label1.winfo_x(), label1.winfo_y()
    positions["moveable_label"] = (x, y)
    dictfile = open("labelposition.txt", "w")   # save new positions
    dictfile.write(str(positions))
    dictfile.close()
```